# Can I intercept and modify a query from iOS to Parse.com in Cloud Code?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

For example, I've got code that looks like this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ParseClass"];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    [Do stuff];
}];
```

Can I -- without modifying the app -- insert an extra parameter into this query? Via Cloud Code or something?

Say, for example, I only wanted to get objects where the score was greater than zero. Or where a "deleted" flag had been set to false.

I'm asking because I'd like to add some filters to data calls, but also have them retroactively apply to users who may not have updated the app yet.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: That would be an amazing feature and I hope that some day they implement it, but no, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

You're out of luck here when running the query client-side. There is no way, without updating your app to make this work.

Your only option is to create a Cloud Code function that runs the query and call that from the client so you can update it ad-hoc without requiring an update from the user.